# Complex event_shape from tfd.Distribution.sample

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to implement a custom tfd.Distribution which represents a complex state transition model (STM).  I need to return a tuple of 2 arrays with different dimensions from an implementation of the abstract method tfd.Distribution._sample_n.  However, I'm running into trouble when the wrapper method (tfd.Distribution.sample) tries to pack these arrays.

An STM is characterises a population which exists in a number of mutually exclusive states. Over time, individuals in the population transition between the states according to a stochastic process.  To represent a realisation of the STM (i.e. a sample), you end up with a vector of length T containing the times at which transitions occurred, and a multidimensional array of shape [T, M, N] where T is the number of timesteps, M is the number of states, and N is the number of individuals in the population.

So far, I have:

```py
class Foo(tfd.Distribution):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(dtype=tf.float32,
                         #...other config here
                        )

    def _sample_n(self, n, seed=None):
        # Sampling algorithm here
        # t.shape = [T]
        # y.shape = [T, M, N]
        return t, y

foo = Foo()
foo.sample()
```

Desired result: calling `foo.sample()` should return a tuple of (tf.tensor, tf.tensor) with shapes [T] and [T, M, N] respectively.

Actual:

```py
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 3
    From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'MyEpidemic/sample/Shape/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [11], [11,3,1000].
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `JointDistribution*` classes [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/g3doc/api_docs/python/index.md); they can handle this.

Note, they are only in `pip install tfp-nightly`.

```
tfp.distributions.JointDistribution
tfp.distributions.JointDistributionCoroutine
tfp.distributions.JointDistributionCoroutine.Root
tfp.distributions.JointDistributionNamed
tfp.distributions.JointDistributionSequential
```

Comment: Many thanks, looks like it might achieve what I want...barring the slightly odd semantics.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's a bit of a weird fit. Are your timesteps autoregressive, or can you sample all of [T] in parallel? I assume the [T,M,N] samples are conditional on the [T] samples, but are they also autoregressive? Have you looked at the tfp.sts package at all?

Comment: Yes, autoregressive -- it's an epidemic process.  I've had a read of tfp.sts -- it's close to what I need, in that the event shape certainly needs to have a "num_time_steps" dimension, but the observed values (x_t) bit of the output needs to be multidimensional, or risk confusing the user by flattening a complex data structure.  Moreover, since my models have a discrete state space, it kinda feels wrong to represent discrete values as floats just for the sake of having them in the same tensor as the time steps (which are floating point, and not necessarily equal intervals).

Comment: Does tfd.HiddenMarkovModel fit the bill? Better for discrete observations than sts.